# Does nodejs Master process utilize all the cpu memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, load-balancing, node-cluster

Trying to understand how nodejs works in terms of cpu memory usage we have 4 instances in prod that are slowing down because of heavy lifting and we have load balancer in place. 
would it make sense to add node-cluster at instance/app level so we can use all the hardware capabilities using `cluster.fork` so all the child processes can also listen to the port directly. what would be better approach add more instances to load balancer or add node-cluster or third party PM2 etc for handling heavy load ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ways of scaling out your node app -- `cluster.fork` or loadbalancing multiple instances -- will work.

If you have loadbalancing working without `pm2` it might not make sense to add it to the mix at this point, because complexity.

One other thing to consider: if your nodejs instances are running `https` servers, not `http` servers, you may want to use nginx as a reverse proxy, and have it handle the https crypto work. You can have nginx forward requests to your node instance at `http://localhost:3000`. `https`-handling is compute intensive, and nginx does it more efficiently than nodejs does.